# incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf"

Tags: c, crash, declaration, implicit

I have a big problem.
This is the header file I created to have a little terminal menu.
The problem is, in function "menu" (italian name) , that when I compile it I get a warning that says 
"[Warning] incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by default]"
And then if I run it it CRASHES.

```
#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER

int numeroOpz = 0;
int selezON = 0;
int tasto;

struct Opzione{
 char *testo;
 int selez;
 };

struct Opzione *opz;

void nuovaOpzione(char *testoOpz){
 strcpy(opz[numeroOpz].testo, testoOpz);   //Il testo dell'opzione viene copiato
 opz[numeroOpz].selez = 0;          //Nessuna opzione viene inizialmente selezionata
 numeroOpz++;
 }

void menu(){
 opz[0].selez = 1;

 while(tasto != 13){
 int i;
 for(i=0;i < numeroOpz;i++){
           if(opz[i].selez == 1){
                    printf("||%s||\n", opz[i].testo);
                           }
           else if(opz[i].selez == 0){
                    printf("%s\n", opz[i].testo);
                           }
           tasto = getch();

           switch (tasto){
                  case 72:  //SU
                     if(selezON > 0){
                         opz[selezON].selez = 0;
                         opz[selezON-1].selez = 1;
                         selezON--;
                                    }
                     else{
                         opz[selezON].selez = 0;
                         opz[numeroOpz-1].selez = 1;
                     }
                  break;
                  case 80:  //GIU
                     if(selezON < numeroOpz){
                         opz[selezON].selez = 0;
                         opz[selezON+1].selez = 1;
                         selezON++;
                                    }
                     else{
                         opz[selezON].selez = 0;
                         opz[0].selez = 1;
                     }
                  break;
                  default:
                         printf("Error\n\n\n\n");
                  break;
                  }
           }

   }
 }

#endif
```

And HERE is the source file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Opzioni.h"

int main(){
nuovaOpzione("Ciao");
nuovaOpzione("Bellaaa");
nuovaOpzione("Hey");

menu();

getch();
return 0;
}
```

I'm just getting crazy, and yes, I searched a lot for help in other questions...
Thanks for helping if you do! :P

btw: the strcpy function in "nuovaOpzione" is a warning as well, but yolo...

Comment: Do no put function body in your header files.

Comment: Do you have a function definition in your header file?  If so, it should be moved to the source file.

Comment: What does your compiler/linker command look like?

Comment: Although `#include <stdio.h>` is not in `"Opzioni.h"`, `#include <stdio.h>` is included in main.c before doing `#include "Opzioni.h"`, so this warning is unexpected.  I think what is posted differs from OP's compilation or another .c file includes "Opzioni.h" without a preceding `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Also suspicious of warning with words "built-in" to describe `printf()`.

Comment: Compiling the code shown in the question does not produce the reported error message. (A message about `getch` is produced.) It is likely the code shown in the question is **not** the code you used to compiler when the message about `printf` was produced. To declare `getch`, you should likely `#include <curses.h>` before using `getch`. If you still receive a message about `printf`, you should check carefully that the files you are compiling are exactly the ones shown in this question.

Comment: `strcpy function in "nuovaOpzione" is a warning as well` is additional evidence that posted code differs from OP's compilation for similar reasons about `printf()` warning .  The main code includes <string.h> an the waring is unexpected.   OP, please post your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jens is right about the printf warning.

For the crashing, based on your program, you need an array for `opz`, not a pointer.

```
struct Opzione opz[1000];
```

Comment: Likely also needs memory allocation for `strcpy(opz[numeroOpz].testo, testoOpz)`.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil OP states 2 problems in the post: "when I compile it I get a warning ..." and "if I run it it CRASHES".  This solution does address the warning (tersely) and crash part.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the include:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: It seems as if stdio.h *is* included before including "Opzioni.h".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ŁukaszL. why do you think that it doesn't answer the question? The error message that is appearing in the title is just that, the compiler is confused about the declaration of `printf`. Probably he is trying to compile the `.h` file alone, as a separate compilation unit. To make *that* error go away, he has to include stdio.h in his `.h` file, that's it. Then he will come to see the next errors.

Comment: Your answer was in late answers queue. It doesn't provide any explanation. And the include is in OP's code.

Comment: @ŁukaszL.what is "late answers queue"? My answer was the first, and two of the other answers refer to it.

Comment: Unless the OP edited the question quickly after entering it (so that Stack Overflow does not show it was edited), then, when this answer was entered, the code shown in the question contains `#include <stdio.h>` before `#include "Opzioni.h"`, and it is the latter file that contains the `printf` call. Thus, a missing `#include <stdio.h>` is **not** the cause of the behavior reported in the question given the code shown, and this answer does not provide a solution. It is, however, likely that the code shown in the question is not the code that caused the reported error message.

Comment: @EricPostpischil some compiler require `#include` directive inside the `.h` when looking up type definitions (I used to have such problems with Visual Studio). It makes it even worse when putting code in the `.h`...

Comment: @Matthieu: No, they do not. If you had any such problem, it was an illusion caused by preprocessor conditionals, subtle language differences (attempting to include C headers with preprocessor conditionals while compiling for C++, et cetera), or similar issues.

Comment: @Matthieu Certainly putting #include directives inside the .h for type definitions is good practice, but never have I seen a compiler _require_ it.  They could come from higher level includes like this not-well-organize code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, chux, OK it makes sense. I was coding in C and the default settings was to use a C++ compiler with pre-compiled headers (if I remember correctly). At the time I thought it was to prevent circular dependencies. It might as well have been a mix-up in my source files and the way the compiler "remembers" the includes it already processed.

Answer (score 0):

> incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf

The problem is that when the compiler first encountered the call to printf(), it made up for itself (that is, implicitly) a definition like:

> printf(char[], char)

but later on you call it with

> printf(char[])

so it complained.

As other poster have said, you should include  to incorporate the proper definition, and on principle don't put code in header files.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the body of `menu()` in the `.c` source file instead (as @ouah pointed out) and add the `#include <stdio.h>` in your `.h` file (as @Jens indicated), as it is mandatory for your compiler to know its signature.

Including code in a `.h` file is *NOT* good practice in C. Some compiler might turn on/off specifics when processing one or the other.